# ZF2 Class PDO not found but PDO is enabled in php config

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, zend-framework2

My zf2 application always worked fine but suddenly I started getting this error

Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found in /home/doaminName/public_html/xxxxx.com/config/autoload/global.php on line 21

My PHP version is native (5.4) and here is the Configure Command from phpinfo. PDO is enabled with this line --enable-pdo=shared.

> './configure' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-exif'
>   '--enable-ftp' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--enable-libxml'
>   '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-pdo=shared' '--enable-soap'
>   '--enable-sockets' '--enable-zip' '--prefix=/usr/local' '--with-bz2'
>   '--with-curl=/opt/curlssl/' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-gd'
>   '--with-gettext' '--with-imap=/opt/php_with_imap_client/'
>   '--with-imap-ssl=/usr' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-kerberos'
>   '--with-libdir=lib64' '--with-libexpat-dir=/usr'
>   '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2/'
>   '--with-mcrypt=/opt/libmcrypt/' '--with-mysql=/usr'
>   '--with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'
>   '--with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config' '--with-openssl=/usr'
>   '--with-openssl-dir=/usr' '--with-pcre-regex=/opt/pcre'
>   '--with-pdo-mysql=shared' '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared' '--with-pic'
>   '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-tidy=/opt/tidy/' '--with-xmlrpc'
>   '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--with-zlib' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr'

Any idea of where the problem is coming from?

Comment: Try `<?php phpinfo();` in a PHP file to see how your PHP is configured. Maybe you need to enable PDO in your `php.ini`? Something changed on your host - do you manage this server? Try restarting Apache.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can try to make it `\PDO` in global.php on line 21

All subsequent calls to PDOException have to be convertad as well.

If it won't work, then your php is built without PDO.

Comment: It has worked so far. I don't get why I  am getting this now. When I change the php version to 5.4 (not native) it works fine though. But that forces me to change all kind of stuff that are not supported in that version.